# How to install libosmesa on ubuntu server?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-14.04, webgl

I tried installing  libosmesa on ubuntu by doing

```
apt-get install libosmesa
```

however, I get the error: package not found.

I am using x64 ubuntu 14 server. How can I install libosmesa on ubuntu 14?

I am trying to get it to work with google chrome running headless on ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `libosmesa6`?

`apt-get install libosmesa6`